# Clear Textbox value in my code

Tags: javascript, html

For some reason the clear function I wrote cannot clear my textbox, but it runs in another html file. Can someone figure out the problem for me? This assignment is due at 12:00 am today, please help! Thanks in advance.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function() {
            var container = document.getElementById("projector");
            var add_img = document.getElementById("add-img");

            function Clear() {
                document.getElementById("xi").value = " ";

            }


            add_img.onclick = function check() {
                var img = document.createElement("img");
                var h = document.getElementById("xi").value;
                var w = document.getElementById("yi").value;

                img.src = 'http://www.cryptocoinsnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/bitcoin-google.jpeg';

                img.setAttribute("height", h);
                img.setAttribute("width", w);

                document.getElementById("projector").appendChild(img);
            }
            //This is my "clear textbox function" but it doesn't run？
            function Clear() {

                document.getElementById("xi").value = " ";
                document.getElementById("xi").value = " ";

            }

            //This is my "clear textbox function" but it doesn't run？

        }

    </script>

    <input type="text" id="xi" value="200">
    <input type="text" id="yi" value="200">
    <input type="button" id="add-img" value="Add Image" onclick='Clear()';>

    <div id="projector"></div>
```

Comment: You have created a Clear function twice.

Comment: Change `<input type="button" id="add-img" value="Add Image" onclick='Clear()';>` to `<input type="button" id="add-img" value="Add Image">`  The `;` in the first instance is in the wrong spot.  Additionally you don't need the `onclick` since you set it in the `onload` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off you have two functions called Clear.

Then its probably easier to call Clear once the click on the button is completed (within the function to handle that).

To end up with..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
    var container = document.getElementById("projector");
    var add_img = document.getElementById("add-img");


    add_img.onclick = function check() {
        var img = document.createElement("img");
            var h = document.getElementById("xi").value;
            var w = document.getElementById("yi").value;

            img.src = 'http://www.cryptocoinsnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/bitcoin-google.jpeg';

            img.setAttribute("height", h);
            img.setAttribute("width", w);

            document.getElementById("projector").appendChild(img);

            Clear();

        }
        //This is my "clear textbox function" but it doesn't run？
        function Clear() {
            document.getElementById("xi").value = " ";
            document.getElementById("yi").value = " ";
        }

        //This is my "clear textbox function" but it doesn't run？

    }

</script>

<input type="text" id="xi" value="200">
<input type="text" id="yi" value="200">
<input type="button" id="add-img" value="Add Image">

<div id="projector"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You've already registered a onclick-event in the code. So don't use the onclick-property in the html. Call the `Clear`-function in the Code like so:

```
add_img.onclick = function check() {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    var h = document.getElementById("xi").value;
    var w = document.getElementById("yi").value;

    img.src = 'http://www.cryptocoinsnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/bitcoin-google.jpeg';

    img.setAttribute("height", h);
    img.setAttribute("width", w);

    document.getElementById("projector").appendChild(img);

    Clear();
}
```

And remove the onclick-property:

```
<input type="button" id="add-img" value="Add Image" />
```

Comment: Move `Clear();` to the end of the function.

Answer (score 0):

You assign you `Clear()` function via html and then override the onclick in your code.
I would just add it to your code.

Like this:

```
add_img.onclick = function check() {
   var img = document.createElement("img");
   var h = document.getElementById("xi").value;
   var w = document.getElementById("yi").value;

   img.src = 'http://www.cryptocoinsnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/bitcoin-google.jpeg';

   img.setAttribute("height", h);
   img.setAttribute("width", w);

   document.getElementById("projector").appendChild(img);
   Clear();
}
```

And remove it from HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="add-img" value="Add Image">
```

**Edit:**

Change you `Clear()` function to this to correct a typo:

```
function Clear() {
   document.getElementById("xi").value = " ";
   document.getElementById("yi").value = " ";
}
```